# variable sum in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have below table data :

```
ID  DATA    VALUE
1   SUM      10
1   SUM      20
1   SUM      30
1   MIN      30
```

Now i want find total of 1 ID.

Comment: And what would the total be?  Does the `DATA` column have any relevance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work :

```
SELECT 
  ID, 
  SUM(CASE(DATA) 
         WHEN 'SUM' THEN VALUE 
         ELSE -VALUE 
      END) TOTAL 
FROM #TEMP 
GROUP BY ID
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
select sum(case when data = 'sum' then value
                when data = 'min' then - value
           end) as total
from t
where id = 1;
```

The data value `SUM` and `MIN` are really, really bad choices because these are the names of SQL functions that do something different.  I might simply suggest `+` and `-` or add/subtract or plus/minus.